# Application Freezing when embedded web browser is loading a url for first time

Tags: wpf, multithreading, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control, prism

I have an Embedded Web browser control in WPF application developed with prism. In Home page on left pane there is a grid implemented which has list of URL's, when double clicked new embedded browser view is resolved and added to the region. I pass URL to object such it loads the web page in web browser control. The issue I am facing here is for the first time when any url is double clicked on the life side grid, the application is freezing till the page is loaded in web browser control I have performed my implementation in xaml.cs by using dispatcher. Please find the code below..

```
        public BrowserView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void WebBrowserControlView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UrlStore = ViewModel.Model.Url;
            string Url = UrlStore;

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { UrlLoad(Url); })); 
        }
        private void UrlLoad(string Url)
        {
//All implementations were run on background thread.
}
```

I am not sure why there is a lag initially. However, for later operations there is no lag.

Comment: I would think if there is any initialization issue. Do you have the WebBrowser control implemented in a separate module? Does this module loads and initializes ***OnDemand***, meaning when you double click the first url? It would be helpful if you could describe when and how much time it takes for the Module to complete initialization. Regards.

Comment: I did not find any initialization issues, yes the web browser control is a seperate module which is initialized on demand. I am not performing any preJIT.